# Xamarin avplayercontroller custom controls

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add some controls to a sample from https://github.com/pro777s/Xam.Forms.VideoPlayer
Modifying these codes from here. I have a created a custom controller.

Not sure how  I am suppose to do it. Help will be appreciated. I need to add two buttons, Previous and Next to play and next and previous track.

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton
{
    
    public CustomButton() : base(UIButtonType.System)
    { }
    public int someValue;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed button");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    ~CustomButton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finalized button");
    }
}

public class CustomPlayerController : AVPlayerViewController 
{
     private AVPlayer _Player;
    private AVAudioUnitEQ aVAudioUnitEQ;
    //   IMusicManager musicManager;
    static CustomPlayerController playerController;
    public static CustomPlayerController GetInstance(AVPlayer player)
    {

        if (playerController == null)
        {
            playerController = new CustomPlayerController(player);
        }
        //DependencyService.RegisterSingleton<IBackGroundPlayer>(playerController);
        return playerController;

    }

    private CustomPlayerController(AVPlayer player)
    {
        _Player = player;
         
    }

    
    private void buttonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //print("button was tapped")
        // replay/comment logic here
    }
     
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        var customView = this.View.Subviews[0] as CustomButton;
        Console.WriteLine("Magic number: " + customView.someValue);
    }

       public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var btn = new CustomButton()
        {
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, 320, 40),
            someValue = 4711
        };
        btn.SetTitle("Click me", UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            //btn.RemoveFromSuperview();
        };
        this.Add(btn);
    }
 }
```

This is the renderer, i have changed this little bit.

```
 AVPlayer player;
    AVPlayerItem playerItem;
    CustomPlayerController _playerViewController;       // solely for ViewController property
    NSObject playCompleteNotification, playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification;
    NSObject playbackBufferEmptyObserver, playbackLikelyToKeepUpObserver, playbackBufferFullObserver;

    public override UIViewController ViewController => _playerViewController;

  
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> args)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(args);

        if (args.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                // Create AVPlayerViewController
             

                // Set Player property to AVPlayer
                player = new AVPlayer();
                _playerViewController = CustomPlayerController.GetInstance (player);
                _playerViewController.Player = player;

                // End of play notification
                playCompleteNotification = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
                    AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                    OnAVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, player.CurrentItem);

                //  Play error occured notification
                playerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification = 
                    AVPlayerItem.Notifications.ObserveItemFailedToPlayToEndTime(OnAVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime);



                 

                // Use the View from the controller as the native control
                SetNativeControl(_playerViewController.View);
            }
               
            SetAreTransportControlsEnabled();
            SetSource();

            args.NewElement.UpdateStatus += OnUpdateStatus;
            args.NewElement.PlayRequested += OnPlayRequested;
            args.NewElement.PauseRequested += OnPauseRequested;
            args.NewElement.StopRequested += OnStopRequested;
            args.NewElement.ShowTransportControlsRequested += OnShowTransportControls;
            args.NewElement.HideTransportControlsRequested += OnHideTransportControls;
        }

        if (args.OldElement != null)
        {
            args.OldElement.UpdateStatus -= OnUpdateStatus;
            args.OldElement.PlayRequested -= OnPlayRequested;
            args.OldElement.PauseRequested -= OnPauseRequested;
            args.OldElement.StopRequested -= OnStopRequested;
            args.OldElement.ShowTransportControlsRequested -= OnShowTransportControls;
            args.OldElement.HideTransportControlsRequested -= OnHideTransportControls;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it is similar to the [PlayRequested](https://github.com/pro777s/Xam.Forms.VideoPlayer/blob/master/Xam.Forms.VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.cs#L134) method in the VideoPlayer. Add a Previous or Next button and implement the function in the custom renderer.

Comment: Jack, I am asking about the UI part, how to put the buttons there.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

If you put the button in the View, it will be overlapped. So one workaround I thought is add the button to the window and remove it when the controller dismiss:

```
UIButton btn { get; set; }

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    
    btn.RemoveFromSuperview();

}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);

    btn.RemoveFromSuperview();
}


public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    btn = new CustomButton()
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(40, 20, 320, 40),
        someValue = 4711
    };

    btn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    btn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue,UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.SetTitle("Click me", UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        //btn.RemoveFromSuperview();
    };

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Add(btn);
}
```

I did not test the remove part as I can't play a video on my side.